# Hibernate bidirectional mapping, saving child does not update parent

Tags: java, hibernate, bidirectional-relation

The first assert statement passes but the second does not. Stepping through the code, the database is being updated properly at each commit. However, the primary entity does not appear to update when the secondary entity object updates.

```
Entity secondary = (Entity) session.get(Entity.class, 2);            
secondary.setPrimary(null); 
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(secondary);
session.getTransaction().commit();

Entity primary = (Entity) session.get(Entity.class, 1);
secondary.setPrimary(primary);
session.beginTransaction();            
session.save(secondary);
session.getTransaction().commit();

Set<Entity> secondarySet;

// If I comment out these two lines, the next assert passes.
secondarySet = primary.getSecondarySet();
assertFalse(secondarySet.isEmpty());

secondary.setPrimary(null);       
session.beginTransaction();            
session.save(secondary);
session.getTransaction().commit();

primary = (Entity) session.get(Entity.class, 1);
secondarySet = primary.getSecondarySet();
assertTrue(secondarySet.isEmpty());
```

I have tried a few unsuccessful solutions, such as adding CascadeType.All to the @OneToMany annotation, and flushing the session. How can I update my primary entity once my secondary entity saves and changes the database?

My Entity class looks like:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(catalog = "catalog", name = "Entity")
public class Entity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id; 
    private Entity primary;
    private Set<Entity> secondarySet;

    public Entity() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primary")
    public Set<Entity> getSecondarySet() {
        return this.secondarySet;
    }

    public void setSecondarySet(Set<Entity> secondarySet) {
        this.secondarySet = secondarySet;
    }

    /**
     * @return primary client if it exists, otherwise null
     */
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) // can be it's own primary
    @JoinTable(catalog = "catalog", name="entitylink",
          joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="secondaryid_")},
          inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="primaryid_")})    
    public Entity getPrimary() {
        return this.primary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(Entity primary) {
        this.primary = primary;
    }
}
```